# Subdomains and webmin - Debian linux

Tags: subdomain, debian, webmin

I have dedicated server with webmin interface. I need this settings - i want to all subdomains of .example.com will be server from one Document Root. How can i achieve that? 
So if i type xxx.example.com and fff.example.com - site will be exactly same. 
I have script which sets up language via its code in subdomain - for example en.example.com and so on.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're using apache, you may use

```
ServerAlias domain.org *.domain.org
```

Please note that you probably need a wildcard entry in your DNS-record.

regards,
/t

Comment: I have setup my virtual host 

`<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName thexxx.com
    ServerAlias www.thexxx.com www.*.thexxx.com *.thexxx.com
    RewriteEngine On
    DocumentRoot /var/www/www/thexxx
    php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/www/thexxx/tmp:/var/www/www/thexxx
</VirtualHost>`

and what do i need to enter as wildcard in DNS record?

Comment: Use either CNAME or A-record, like *.example.com.